# Nutch 1.14 in windows giving exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

Tags: hadoop, nutch

```
While I am running Apache Nutch 1.14 I am getting following exception.

Injector: starting at 2018-07-08 10:15:56
Injector: crawlDb: crawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:609)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:977)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:187)
```

I have installed Java and put hadoop native libraries(i.e, winutils.exe) in c:\winutil\bin and pointed to HADOOP_HOME.

Not to sure how to resolve it and cannot find any documentation how to run Nutch 1.14 in windows. If any one has solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to get around that error is from this thread:
[Nutch on windows: ERROR crawl.Injector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147431/nutch-on-windows-error-crawl-injector)

The key is to comment out the following line:

```
JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH="`cygpath -p -w "$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH"`"
```

Read the README.txt under $NUTCH_HOME/lib/native for more info regarding hadoop binaries which is what the JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH is referencing.